# Add logo background color

Tags: c#, itext

I am adding a logo on the top of the page:

```
iTextSharp.text.Image logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("/logos/my_logo.png"));
logo.ScalePercent(60f);
document.Add(logo);
```

How I can add a logo background color?

(Width: Full page, Height: 1.5x logo height)

Comment: Surely the simplest way is to have a logo image with that colour already as the background

Comment: Why not create the logo including the background

Comment: I want the background to cover 100% width of the page while the logo is something like 20%

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you...

For background image

```
string imageFilePath = parent + "/logos/my_logo.png";
iTextSharp.text.Image jpg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageFilePath);
jpg.ScaleToFit(1700, 1000);
jpg.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.UNDERLYING;
jpg.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
document.Add(jpg);
```

**Edit**

For the background color i think you can use the below code:

```
public void onDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
{
    super.onEndPage(writer, document);
    PdfContentByte content = writer.getDirectContent();
    content.setColorFill(BaseColor.GREEN);
    content.rectangle(writer.getPageSize().getLeft(), writer.getPageSize().getBottom(),
                      writer.getPageSize().getWidth(), writer.getPageSize().getHeight());
    content.Rectangle(35f,55f, 520f, 750f ,20f);
    content.eoFill();        
}
```

May be you can change the values of rectangle width and height from this code for your case

**Edit**

Changing background color of a particular cell.

```
header = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(market_data_list[i], grid_data_heading));
header.Colspan = 2;
header.HorizontalAlignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
header.BackgroundColor =new BaseColor(238,233,233);
market_table.AddCell(header); //adds cell to the table
```

Comment: Where are you adding the background color? Can you adapt your code so that the image gets a green background?

Answer (score 0):

Best fit option:

You can come up with background image which can take complete width of a page. we can do that with third party tools(merging two images) even in paint app.

Second option:

I believe,it is better to have a table layout. You can divide your page in cells with no border and keep your logo in one of them, rest will fill with the background color. Make sure your background should match with logo background.

Code snippet :

```
       public void writeDocument()
          {
          Document _document = new Document(new Rectangle(PageSize.A3));
          var table = new PdfPTable(2);
          PdfPCell[] cells = new PdfPCell[2];
          PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(); 
          cell.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
          cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(51, 102,102);
          cells[0] = new PdfPCell(cell);
          iTextSharp.text.Image logo =         

iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("/logos/my_logo.png"));
          PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(); 
           cell1.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
          cell1.Image =logo ;
          cells[1] = new PdfPCell(cell1);

         PdfPRow row = new PdfPRow(cells);
         table.Rows.Add(row);
        _document.Add(table);

         }
```